# Parsing strings in RPLY

Tags: python, regex, ply

```py
lg.add("STRING", r"\"(\\.|[^\"\\])*\"")
```

I have this rule in RPLY but when I try to parse e.g. `"string1"` it parses it as `"string1"`. How can I make it parse `"string1"` into `string1`?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and explain what should be matched and what not exactly? For example, are you only looking for `string1` when it is in between `" "` or should any occurence be matched?

Comment: Try using lookarounds `(?<=\")(?:\\.|[^\"\\])*(?=\")` https://regex101.com/r/uehawg/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Ply, RPly's lexer does not provide any mechanism to execute an action on a lexical token. What you get from the RPly lexer is a `Token` object containing the matched text, unmodified.

You can use a unit production in your grammar in order to impose a transformation on a given token type. For example, you could put the following rule in your grammar:

```py
@pg.production('string : STRING')
def dequote(p):
    return p[0].getstr()[1:-1]
```

Then, everywhere else in your grammar, you use the non-terminal `string` instead of the terminal `STRING`.

I'm ignoring the needs of RPython here; if you're actually using RPython, you probably need to wrap the return value of `dequote` in some kind of object instead of returning a `str`. The above snippet works with Python 3.9 (for example). But, of course, if you're not using RPython, you could just use Ply as your parser generator.

Comment: This is an useful answer. Thank you so much. I'm using RPLY for the sake of it's better API.

Comment: @maDev. OK. Out of curiosity, why do you feel that the RPLY API is better? The fact that it is missing a useful feature (actions during lexical analysis) would seem to indicate that the API is oversimplified and inflexible. At least, that's my take.

Comment: As I said I like it is because of it's API. Also implementing the same parser in PLY that I wrote in RPLY took longer time.